# Error 53 : File not found instead all DLL's are present in path

Tags: c++, vba, excel, dll, sqlite

I created a DLL(using C++) which is dependent on `sqlite3.dll`(for database access & sqlcipher) and I am trying to access it using `VBA`. In `VBA` I am using following declaration  :

```
Declare Function GetData_VBA Lib "xyz.dll" (ByVal path As String, ByVal id As String, ByRef inputArr() As String, ByRef output() As String) As Boolean
```

Earlier when the DLL was not dependent on `sqlite3.dll` it was working fine, but when I introduced `sqlite3.dll` it started throwing error

> Error 53 : xyz.dll not found

I tried changing the declaration to

```
 Declare Function GetData_VBA Lib "C:\documents\user\...\projects\xyz.dll" (ByVal path As String, ByVal id As String, ByRef inputArr() As String, ByRef output() As String) As Boolean
```

but still its showing the same thing. I used `dependency walker` to check all the dependency on `xyz.dll`. I tried putting all `xyz.dll` & `sqlite3.dll` in same location but still same error.

Comment: Is your dll tested in the C++ environment?

Comment: Is the location of sqlite3.dll in your PATH environment variable, if not then consider adding it.  Alternatively, if you are controlling its install location then you could load it manually with LoadLibrary from the specific place.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't an architecture mismatch (32/64 bit) between your *.dll* and *sqlite3.dll*?

Comment: @TSion.D.P Yes, it is working. I debugged code using VBA(Excel) and it is working fine.

Comment: @CristiFati already checked.. there is no mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

The `cryptlib.lib` was missing on which `sqlite3.dll` was dependent. I have provided the .lib file and it worked.